# (Visual Studio Code) How to indent selection?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently started using Visual Studio Code, and I'm wondering if there is any command to automatically indent a selected section of code. I'm looking for something similar to the Re-Indent Current Line or Selection option in Netbeans. I tried using Reindent Selected Lines, but that isn't doing anything. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: There is a shortcut to format a  selection - look for it in your keyboard shortcuts. Ctrl-K Ctrl-F.

Comment: Hmm, that seems like what I'm looking for, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, when I try to use it I just get the error message: "There is no selection formatter for 'haxe'-files installed."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>' formats the current selection: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/05/19/format-the-current-document-or-selection/

'<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>' formats the whole document including indents.

Comment: That's a helpful command, thanks. It does help with indentation. Although, it also makes some changes to the formatting of my code that I don't like, so I would still like a command to format only certain lines, if it exists.

Comment: After having another look, you can format selection with CTRL + K, CTRL + F.  Read more:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/05/19/format-the-current-document-or-selection/ - will update answer

Comment: Someone suggested that in a comment on my original post too. When I try to use that key combination I just get the error message: "There is no selection formatter for 'haxe'-files installed." Still, it's looking to me like the first shortcut you suggested is the closest thing VSCode has to what I'm looking for. Thanks a bunch.